# Macbook Pro Hard Drive won't show up on disk startup

Tags: hard-drive, boot, macbook-pro, disk-utility

I have a Macbook Pro from 2007. It came with an installation CD for 10.4.8.

The first problem is that it won't even recognize the installation CD even though the CD seems perfectly fine. So I used another installation CD just to get me to the Disc Utility dialogue box. I went through the steps to erase the hard drive. However when I attempted to reboot the machine using Disc Startup there was no option for me to select the hard drive. Of course, since I don't have the appropriate installation disk in it won't let me install anything.

*What are my options?* Do I need to ask Apple to send me a new installation CD for this computer? And why wouldn't the hard drive show up in the Startup options?

Comment: Wait.. what? You erased the drive with an installation CD and then you say that you don't have the appropriate installation CD? And: If you erased the hard drive it won't show up in start up options anymore.

Comment: Did you go through the install process already on this disc that was bootable? You can't boot to the hard disk until you actually install a boot loader, and subsequently an OS.

Answer (score 0):

Get back into disk utility, Click on your disk on the right hand side, now on the left find partitions, and create one partition with options GUID parititon table. There is no need to reboot. After you have created the GUID partition setup should allow you to begin installation on the partition you created.